# Which plugin can do horizontal scrolling of RSS feeds in WordPress

Tags: plugins, customization, javascript, rss, feed

I need a plugin which can do horizontal scrolling of RSS feeds in wordpress, I have got a vertical scrolling RSS feeds but cannot find a horizontal one

Comment: What's the name of that widget? Maybe it is pretty easy to switch it to horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that present headlines in a horizontal scroll tend to be called tickers. (Probably due to there resemblance to old-school ticker tape printers.)

Anyway, try these:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/news-ticker/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-news-ticker-plugin/ (may not do RSS)
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/accessible-news-ticker/

They should all do pretty much the same thing, but they will differ in their appearance. If you don't mind about the appearance, I would recommend the first due to the ease of management.